# Typescript & Moment.js: Format Date to ISO DateTime string

Tags: typescript, momentjs

I'm using Typescript 3.4.3.

I need to format a `Date` object to an ISO DateTime string.

Could someone add some straightforward helping example?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using `toISOString`

```
var dateObj = new Date('2019-05-28');
moment(dateObj).toISOString();
```